# how to capture Post and Get in Webform and store in Strings

Tags: delphi

I have an application that gets inside a webform one html page with 2 fields, what I know and how I can capture and store strings in the values ​​of the methods Post when you click the send button

Comment: Need more details. Are you downloading the HTML yourself? Are you hooking into a web browser?

Comment: well my application has a component that loads an HTML webrowser1 with a form with 2 inputs sending data by post method and submit button when clicking submit button I want intercepitar values ​​of two inputs and store in Strings

Comment: Use the `OnBeforeNavigate2` event. It has a `PostData` parameter that you can extract the values from.

Comment: I found another example as I am new to delphi wanted to know how to run this code in a button to test.

http://delphi.xcjc.net/viewthread.php?tid=43410

Comment: You don't run that code directly. It needs to be inside the `TWebBrowser.OnBeforeNavigate2` event handler. What you can do is use a button to call `WebBrowser1.Navigate()` to go to a webpage, then the `OnBeforeNavigate2` event will be triggered. So first `Navigate()` to the webpage that has the webform you want to capture (`OnBeforeNavigate2` event is triggered without any `PostData` value) then fill out and submit the webform (`OnBeforeNavigate2` event is triggered again with `PostData` value provided).

Comment: forgive my ignorance and where I'd put the code? , Found in the Object Inspector tab component events webBrowser1 OnBeforeNavigate2 tried pasting the code it more not worked

Comment: Then you did something wrong. Please update your question with the actual code you are trying to use.

Comment: thank you, I got to run this forum and best of delphi and powerful